# MySql Update field when selecting by that field

Tags: mysql

I want to update a field, but I can only identify the row to be updated by selecting from that field, eg:

```
UPDATE alumni_feedback_questions
SET question_text = 'Basic Skills / Foundation Learning'
WHERE question_text =  'Basic Skills and Foundation Learning'
```

I am sure this works in SQL server, but does not seem to work in MySql.

I am pretty sure the problem is because I am doing the select on the value that is changing, and I can see why this would be problematic. I would have thought the designers would have thought of this situation and made it do the select first, therefore identifying the fields to be changed before changing them.

I also tried:

```
 UPDATE alumni_feedback_questions
SET question_text = 'Basic Skills / Foundation Learning'
WHERE ID =  (
                SELECT ID
                FROM alumni_feedback_questions
                WHERE question_text =  'Basic Skills and Foundation Learning'
            )
```

But that also does not work.

Can this be done - I do not want to have to select eh ids and manually insert them-there must be a better way?

I have seen something about joining the same table to the select?

UPDATE - The error message I am getting from this `UPDATE` statement is:

```
You can't specify target table 'alumni_feedback_questions' for update in FROM clause    0.016 sec
```

Comment: It does [work](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d24a3a/1) also in MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first suggestion is correct. This is valid SQL to update a column, based on the column's current value:

```
UPDATE alumni_feedback_questions
SET question_text = 'Basic Skills / Foundation Learning'
WHERE question_text =  'Basic Skills and Foundation Learning'
```

To check it's actually selecting something, and hence able to update, do a select:

```
SELECT question_text
WHERE question_text =  'Basic Skills and Foundation Learning'
```

If you get zero results, you text doesn't exist as you have it.

Comment: am I misunderstanding the error message? I have updated the question to include it

Comment: Is your error from the second example? Because the first one shouldn't error. Did you run the SELECT to check the results?

Comment: thank you-that is correct - safe mode was on and that was why the update was being prevented. Ill upvote if you include safe mode in your answer